# Java Iterative Add All Within Arrays.asList

Tags: java, list

Given the following list, how would I approach iteratively adding elements of type `FactoryWithArgs` with arguments `0 - 100`, while still keeping this code in (essentially) one line?

```
final List<Factory> list = new ArrayList<Factory>(Arrays.asList(
        new Factory0(), new Factory1(), new Factory2(), 
        new FactoryWithArgs(0), new FactoryWithArgs(1), ... ,
        new FactoryWithArgs(99), new FactoryWithArgs(100),
        new Factory4(), new Factory5()));
```

Comment: Why don't you use loop?

Comment: It's mainly a readability thing, I want to visually see all the factories in list as the list is initialized... it's just a personal preference. My question is, can you even use a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to @Brian comment on "double brace" initialization being a no no, here's another suggestion.

For the `FactoryWithArgs` class I would make a `FactoryWithArgsMaker` class that is designed to make `FactoryWithArgs` objects as a `List`.

Something like:

```
public static class FactoryWithArgsMaker {
    public static List<FactoryWithArgs> makeNew(int start, int end) {
        List<FactoryWithArgs> list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
            list.add(new FactoryWithArgs(i));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

As long as the order of your "Factories" don't matter in your list, and with Java 8 `Stream`s you can initialize your list in one line like this:

```
List<Factory> list = Stream.concat(
    Arrays.asList(
        new Factory0(), new Factory1(), new Factory2(), 
        new Factory3(), new Factory4(), new Factory5()
    ).stream(),
    FactoryWithArgsMaker.makeNew(0, 100).stream()
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `Stream.concat()` takes the contents of `Arrays.asList()` and the `List<FactoryWithArgs>`, returned from `FactoryWithArgsMaker.makeNew()`, and combines them into a single stream which we then convert back into a List (`.collect(Collectors.toList()`);

Comment: Never do this. This creates an anonymous inner class and the code is being executed before the constructor you're calling itself. An instance is bound to the parent object and thus, even if no reference to the parent object exists anymore, references to the object of the anonymous inner class will keep it alive (indirectly). This can cause memory leaks. Never ever use `{{}}`. It's the worst idea somebody came up with (although it looks cool).

Comment: Much better. :) I like the stream approach. And btw: You can keep the order of the objects by splitting the `Arrays.asList(...)` statement into two (0..2, ...makeNew(0, 100), 3..5), because the `.stream()` call creates a sequential stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final List<Factory> list = new ArrayList<Factory>();        
    list.add(new Factory0());
    list.add(new Factory1());
    list.add(new Factory2());
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        list.add(new FactoryWithArgs(i));
    }
    list.add(new Factory4());
    list.add(new Factory5());
```

You can put it in a method, if you prefer.

Comment: I want to do this in one line, most likely using `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: I think, it's possible only if you write by hand all 106 objects you want to add

Comment: @budi you could use a static method with the loop as initializer. Or you can use a static block (`{ for (...) {...} }`) right below the list declaration as macara suggests.